# In the R, meet problem 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' when using 'by' function

Tags: r, double

I was trying to use `by` to gain both the mean and sd for data

here is my code

```
dstats <- function(x)(c(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)))

aggregate(mtcars[vars],by=list(am=mtcars$am), FUN = dstats)
```

This works fine, I got

```
 am  mpg.mean    mpg.sd   hp.mean     hp.sd   wt.mean     wt.sd
1  0 17.147368  3.833966 160.26316  53.90820 3.7688947 0.7774001
2  1 24.392308  6.166504 126.84615  84.06232 2.4110000 0.6169816
```

In order to get neat diagram, I want to seperate by `mtcars$am`,I tried

```
by(mtcars[vars],mtcars$am, FUN=dstats)
```

Then I meet

```
Error during wrapup: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I don't think the number is the data.frame is character, because I can use `aggregate` properly.
I wonder what's the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`by` works on the data.frame that is split by `mtcars$am`, so your function needs to work on a data.frame instead of a vector, so example below I use sapply to go through each column and calculate mean and sd:

```
by(mtcars[vars],mtcars$am, FUN = function(u)sapply(u,dstats)) 
mtcars$am: 0
           mpg       hp        wt
mean 17.147368 160.2632 3.7688947
sd    3.833966  53.9082 0.7774001
------------------------------------------------------------ 
mtcars$am: 1
           mpg        hp        wt
mean 24.392308 126.84615 2.4110000
sd    6.166504  84.06232 0.6169816
```

It's not so easy to get back the same format as your output for aggregate which is a nested data.frame:

```
res = aggregate(mtcars[vars],by=list(am=mtcars$am), FUN = dstats)
class(res$hp)
[1] "matrix"
# to get mean hp for different groups, you have to do:
res$hp[,"mean"]
[1] 160.2632 126.8462
```

To get something similar with by, it's a bit more elaborate:

```
res = do.call(rbind,
by(mtcars[vars],mtcars$am,function(i){
unlist(lapply(i,dstats))
})
)
res = data.frame(am=levels(factor(mtcars$am)),res)

  am mpg.mean   mpg.sd  hp.mean    hp.sd  wt.mean     wt.sd
0  0 17.14737 3.833966 160.2632 53.90820 3.768895 0.7774001
1  1 24.39231 6.166504 126.8462 84.06232 2.411000 0.6169816
```